# What is 'Normalized frequency in the range [0,1)', à la DTMF & Goertzel algorithm

Tags: math, signal-processing, fft, dtmf

I have a functioning DTMF program. It takes a larger signal and breaks it up into many small components, then analyzes each segment with an FFT to determine if the magnitude of the response for a particular "bin", corresponding to a specific frequency, is present, thereby indicating that the number which is respresented by that frequency has been pressed, straight forward enough, but I want to implement the Goertzel Algorithm of the library jmathstudio and I can't quite figure out how to go about searching for the frequency I want. the documentation says this:

[image]

I construct the bins like this, the term '200' is dictated by the fact that my FFT is currently of size 400, and 2000 is determined by the fact that the sample rate is 4000.

```
int sixNineSeven = (int)(697.0*200/2000);
int sevenSevenZero = (int)(770.0*200/2000);
int eightFiveTwo = (int)(852.0*200/2000);
int nineFourOne = (int)(941.0*200/2000);

int twelveZeroNine = (int)(1209.0*200/2000);
int thirteenThirtySix = (int)(1336.0*200/2000);
int fourteenSeventySeven = (int)(1477.0*200/2000);
```

I guess the main thing I need to do is this step:

Normalized frequency in the range [0,1)

But does that mean that I can totally ignore the sample frequency?

I suppose I would be doing this Geortzel operation in lieu of an FFT, so should I just search for this normalized frequency in each of the small segments?

But when I do this:

```
   Complex coeff = su.goertzelFrequencyAnalysis(new Vector(c), (float)(1/697));

   System.out.println("coeff "+coeff);
```

My output is just a bunch of garbage like this:

```
   coeff org.JMathStudio.DataStructure.Complex@5e228a02
   coeff org.JMathStudio.DataStructure.Complex@7bd63e39
   coeff org.JMathStudio.DataStructure.Complex@2e8f4fb3
   coeff org.JMathStudio.DataStructure.Complex@42b988a6
```

Comment: Does w=1 correspond to the sampling frequency or one half of it? You might want to check for integer division (with result 0) and use `float(1)/697` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'coeff' is the object of type Complex and hence to get real and imaginary part do following:

System.out.println("coeff = "+coeff.getRealPart() +" i"+coeff.getImaginaryPart());

Comment: Hi Bhavya! So then, just to be clear, how would I use the goertzel function to check an input signal for the 697 frequency?